# Getting data from my database via my api(express) in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making my first mern app and i want to populate the dashboard when someone logs in i was thinking that I should make a get request in my server and call my database in the get request and do the work from there but I heard somewhere that I shouldn't do this because its dangerous to call sensitive data in get request , so I am not sure that how I should get that data in my react app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Post request.

I Recommend the Axios Library it is the most used HTTP Request library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

then do

```
axios.post("https://url.de/request", {
   data1: "hallo",
   data2: "secret data"
})
```

in express the data is  then in `req.body.data1`

EDIT:  the Data is only secure when the url starts with https://